# Animando con canvas javascript

Tags: javascript-objeto, animación

estoy algo trabado con este ejercicio, lo que tengo que hacer es animar este circulo en JJavascript y tengo el siguiente código pero no se como completarlo.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//ctx.arc(x, y, radio, angulo inicial, angulo final, contrario a las manecillas)
ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";

for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i = i + 0.2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.arc(190 * i - 10 ,150,15,0, Math.PI * i, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
#canvas{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "400" height = "300"></canvas>
```

Entiendo que tengo hacer una función que refresque cada determinado tiempo para completar el circulo pero ya estoy muy cansado si alguien pudiese explicarme seria buenísimo.  En la página de la universidad nos ponen este ejemplo

```js
function miFuncion() {
  setInterval(funcionAlerta, 3000);
}

function funcionAlerta() {
  document.write("Ya pasaron 3 segundos!" + "<br>");
}

miFuncion();
```

Answer (score 1):

El **canvas** es un **lienzo**, un papel en blanco en el cual puedes pintar un dibujo, para crear una animación deberías poder **pintar** y **borrar** por completo este **lienzo** tantas veces como sea posible, para de esta forma crear el efecto de **animación entre dibujos**. Esto lo puedes hacer posible entre algunas de las opciones disponibles con **setInterval**

Cabe destacar que en cada iteración **necesitas borrar el lienzo** para que un dibujo no se pinte por encima del otro, sino que siempre pintes el dibujo con los datos actualizados.

```js
/*
* Declaracion de variables
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var alto = canvas.height;
var ancho = canvas.width;
var fps = 10;
var intervalo = 1000 / fps;
var i = 0;

/*
* Función encargada de borrar el canvas en cada iteración
*/
function borrarCanvas() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ancho, alto);
}

/*
* Función encargada de pintar el canvas en cada iteración
*/
function pintarCanvas() {
 if(i <= 2){
   i += 0.2; 
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
  ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.arc(190 * i - 10, 150, 15, 0, Math.PI * i, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

/*
* En cada iteración se borra primero el canvas y luego se pinta
*/
function repitarCanvas() {
 borrarCanvas();
 pintarCanvas();
}

/*
* Ejecuta una instrucción indefinidamente cada un cierto periodo de tiempo
*/
setInterval(repitarCanvas, intervalo)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "400" height = "300"></canvas>
```

**Ejemplo en JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/wpj51qdL/20/

Comment: No he borrado el enlace a JSFiddle, pero te he creado el fragmento ejecutable en tu respuesta, para que se pueda ver la ejecución aquí. Puedes crear un fragmento ejecutable pulsando `Ctrl + M` mientras escribes una pregunta o respuesta